# Lookup and return another cell value with a gap of cell in between

Tags: excel, vba, match, vlookup, multiple-value

I am basically stuck in this VBA as I did not know how to lookup 2 cells and return with another cell value. It might be solve with reading project name to lookup first and then reading the week number to match and return the phase in grey area, but to get the 2 lookup together is difficult for me.

[This is the first sheet where the input come in as week number and date in each phase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ1gI.png)

[The second sheet will search the project number and week number, return the phase in column J and next.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPkYR.png)

Comment: You didn't post any VBA code. What did you try so far, and what did you observe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a couple of [Dictionary Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) as look-ups to the Project rows and Week columns.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Macro()

    Const SHT_PRJ = "Project"
    Const COL_ID_PRJ = "E"
    Const COL_PH1 = "F" ' Phase 1
    Const ROW_HDR_PRJ = 2 ' header

    Const SHT_DEM = "Demand"
    Const COL_ID_DEM = "D"
    Const ROW_HDR_DEM = 1
    Const MAX_PH = 6 ' phases 1 to 6

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsIn As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim iRow As Long, iLastRow As Long, iCol() As Integer, iLastCol As Integer
    Dim iColWk As Integer
    Dim iColor As Variant, sWk As String, iPh As Integer

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsIn = wb.Sheets(SHT_PRJ)

    Dim dict As Object, dictWk As Object, key
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictWk = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' build lookup to row for ID
    iLastRow = wsIn.Cells(Rows.Count, COL_ID_PRJ).End(xlUp).Row
    For iRow = ROW_HDR_PRJ + 1 To iLastRow
        key = Trim(wsIn.Cells(iRow, COL_ID_PRJ))
        If dict.exists(key) Then
            MsgBox "Duplicate key " & key, vbCritical, "Row " & iRow
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Len(key) > 0 Then
            dict.Add key, iRow
        End If
    Next

    ' build look up to column for week
    Set wsOut = wb.Sheets(SHT_DEM)
    iLastCol = wsOut.Cells(ROW_HDR_DEM, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For Each cell In wsOut.Cells(ROW_HDR_DEM, 1).Resize(1, iLastCol)
        key = Trim(cell.Value)
        If dictWk.exists(key) Then
            MsgBox "Duplicate week " & key, vbCritical, "Col " & cell.Column
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Len(key) > 0 Then
            dictWk.Add key, cell.Column
        End If
    Next

     ' update demand sheet
    ReDim iCol(MAX_PH)
    iLastRow = wsOut.Cells(Rows.Count, COL_ID_DEM).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In wsOut.Cells(ROW_HDR_DEM + 1, COL_ID_DEM).Resize(iLastRow)
        iColor = cell.Interior.ColorIndex
        key = Trim(cell.Value)
        ' each project
        If Len(key) > 0 And iColor <> xlColorIndexNone Then '-4142
            
            iRow = dict(key) ' row on project sheet
            If iRow < 1 Then
                 MsgBox "ID " & key & " not found", vbCritical, _
                        wsOut.Name & " Row " & cell.Row
                 Exit Sub
            Else
                
                ' get week numbers for each phase
                For iPh = 1 To MAX_PH
                    sWk = wsIn.Cells(iRow, COL_PH1).Offset(0, 2 * (iPh - 1))
                    If Len(sWk) > 0 Then
                        ' look up week to column
                        iCol(iPh) = dictWk(sWk)
                        If iCol(iPh) < 1 Then
                            MsgBox "Week " & sWk & " not found", vbCritical, _
                                   wsOut.Name & " Row " & cell.Row
                            Exit Sub
                        Else
                            ' update sheet
                            wsOut.Cells(cell.Row, iCol(iPh)) = "Phase " & iPh
                        End If
                     End If
                Next
               
                ' fill in gaps with previous
                For iColWk = iCol(1) To iCol(MAX_PH)
                   Set rng = wsOut.Cells(cell.Row, iColWk)
                   If rng.Value = "" Then
                       rng.Value = rng.Offset(0, -1).Value
                   End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox dict.Count & " projects processed"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This works so well. I learned something new from your help. Appreciate your time & help :)

Comment: I have a question, I tried changing this code for the fill gaps with previous to change to fill gaps with next phase.

' fill in gaps with previous
                For iColWk = iCol(1) To iCol(MAX_PH)
                   Set rng = wsOut.Cells(cell.Row, iColWk)
                   If rng.Value = "" Then
                       rng.Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
                   End If

But it only works on the 1st cell, other blank cell still blank.

Comment: @zaid if you have 2 blanks to fill the next cell to the first blank will also be blank. Try working backwards `For iColWk = iCol(MAX_PH) To iCol(1) Step -1`

Comment: Hi! Need your help again - should I open a new post? It on the same VBA, I added 2 more phase (phase 1 to 8) and need to debug at Set rng = wsOut.Cells(cell.Row, iColWk)

Comment: @zaid Does it not work if you change `Const MAX_PH = 6` to `8` ?

Comment: I changed it already, for the first row it is a success but the next row isn't as there is run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. When I clicked debug, it highlighted Set rng = wsOut.Cells(cell.Row, iColWk) = Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Previously I already add phase 7 and it works normally. Not sure why it showed error for phase 8

Comment: @Zaid Do all the weeks in Phase 8 appear in row 1 on Demand sheet ? I think it's a data issue not a code problem. I could add some debug code if you can't find it.